# VB.Net Program with COM ActiveX capabilities

Tags: vb.net, com, interop, automation

Say I created a program with a textbox on it and a button that does something with the text in the textbox.

How do I make that program COM visible, load it and automate it from another project?

My goal is to be able to automate the program using COM:

```
Dim myProj as object = createObject("myProgram")
myProj.setText("Hello World")
myProj.buttonClickEvent()
```

Similar to how you can load a new excel and automate via interop:

```
dim xl as object = createobject("excel.application")
Dim wb as object = xl.workbooks.add
Dim ws as object = wb.worksheets(1)
ws.cells(1,1) = "i love stackoverflow"
```

How do programs do this?  I'm looking for the answer VB.Net specific.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is well covered in the MSDN Library.  The walk-through for VB.NET is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x66s8zcd.aspx

Comment: This tells you to start a new class library.  But what if I want my forms project to be the reference, not a DLL file?  If a COM object class is in my project, I've been able to access routines in the class from an external program, but I want the interface of my program to be automated via interop/com/activex and I dont want to use APIs like findwindow, sendmessage, etc

Comment: Hans, I want to be able to say createObject("myProj") and have the interface of my program appear. Then i want to have access to subs and functions established in the MyProj

Comment: You are talking about out-of-process automation, similar to Office interop.  No, not well supported by .NET

Comment: I appreciate your information sir, but with all due respect, the question wasn't how well supported is out of process automation in .NET, but rather how is it done (if it can be done).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page should give you the necessary details you will need: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/MusaExposingCOM.aspx

This process that you want is normally called "exposing a COM interface", this is done via early binding or late binding. Early binding means the methods (locations) are known when you create your program, late binding means the methods (locations) are looked up when you run the program. Late binding, I think, is a little slower but the lookup only has to happen once. This is negligible.